# Wait the end of a JQuery event to execute an other

Tags: focus, jquery

I actually have a form with a JQuery focusOut event on some input.
But if the focus is on one of this input and the user want to submit. I need to wait the end of the focusOut event before executing the submit event.

Someone know how to do it?

Comment: can you show some code what you have tried so far? or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard using a pair of flags. If you want to hold up the form submission pending the completion of something, just:

1. Set a flag (`inProgress` or whatever) when you start the thing you want to wait for
2. Hook the submit event
3. If the `inProgress` flag is set, cancel the submit event and set a flag saying the form needs submitting (`submitPending` or whatever)
4. When the other thing completes, clear the `inProgress` flag, and if `submitPending` is set, submit the form

It's important that you know that the thing *will* complete. You don't want to cancel the submission in #3 if you don't know, for sure, that #4 will fire.

So for instance, assuming `#theField` is the field and `#theForm` is the form, it would look something like this:

```
(function() {
    var inProgress = false,
        submitPending = false;

    // #2
    $("#theForm").submit(function() {
        if (inProgress) {
            // #3
            submitPending = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("#theField").on("focusOut", function() {
        inProgress = true;
        startThingThatTakesTimeLikeAnimationOrAjax(function() {
            // This is the completion callback of the thing that takes time

            // #4

            // No longer in progress
            inProgress = false;

            // Submit if one is pending
            if (submitPending) {
                $("#theForm").submit();
            }
        });
    });
})();
```